# Unit test logging (use mocha, supertest, and chai) of restful api built with express, node.js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I write the a simple unit test with mocha, chai and supertest.

```
describe('controller.CWEManagementAPI', function () {
it('should be able to say hello', function() { 
    var request = require('supertest')
    , express = require('express');

    var app = express();

    app.get('/user', function(req, res){
        res.send(201, { name: 'tobi' });
    });

    request(app)
    .get('/user')
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .expect(200)
    .end(function(err, res){
        if (err) return done(err);
        console.log('test');
        assert.equal( res.body.name, 'tobi');
        done()
    });
});
});
```

But the problem is that : the `console.log('test')` is not executed.
So I think the `assert.equal( res.body.name, 'tobi');` is not executed either.
And so I write the code without unit testing, like :

```
var request = require('supertest')
, express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res){
res.send(201, { name: 'tobi' });
});

request(app)
   .get('/user')
   .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
   .expect('Content-Length', '20')
   .expect(201)
   .end(function(err, res){ 
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(res.body.name);
    console.log('done');
    process.exit();
   });
```

And the `console.log()`  are all executed. so I don't know why the first code can not show the logging info.

Comment: when you say that you are running with & without unit testing, what's the command you are using to run it?

Comment: sorry, I use the "mocha unittest.js"  to run the unit testcase. And use "node test.js" to run the common js file.

Comment: "it('should be able to say hello', function() {  " this code should be edited "it('should be able to say hello', function(done) { " .  Then the result is excepted. Because this situation should be used with Asynchronous mode of mocah.

Comment: oops.. seems you have figured it yourself... just noticed your comment after posting the answer.. have a great day

Answer (score 9):

What you are trying to run is an asynchronous test with mocha. So the test case should receive a callback parameter to invoke once it's done with its actions.

You are invoking done() at the end but haven't received it as a parameter.

**change**

```
it('should be able to say hello', function() {
}
```

**to**

```
it('should be able to say hello', function(done) {
}
```